# Java add line to specific part of text file

Tags: java, windows, loops, random, helper

**COMMENTS BELOW ARE ANSWERING ANOTHER QUESTION, THIS IS THE ONLY WAY FOR ME TO ASK NEW QUESTION...**

Okay. My program is like writing info on a .txt file. Currently it is writing info to end of the text file like so:

```
t/1/15/12
o/1/12/3
o/2/15/8
... (lots of lines like this.. all with different numbers)
o/1/16/4
```

Then.. when I add line using:

```
BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C://Users/Mini/Desktop/Eclipse/Japda/map/" +Numbers.map +".txt"), true));
            fw.newLine();
            fw.write(RightPanel.mode.charAt(0) +"/" +ID +"/" +Numbers.middlex +"/" +Numbers.middley);
            fw.close();
```

It adds the line I want to but currently to the end of the text file.. However I would like it to write that line to a specific part of the text files.. I already do know the number of the line I want to write it.. (It is calculated depending on other lines..) :D Is there any way to do it? Or what would be the best way to edit one specific line in the middle of that text file?

Comment: The Javadoc link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: I just saw that you put the code up here.  Just a quick glance, but you can't use "==" with Strings.  You have to do:  if (answer.equals(rightanswer)){

Comment: Also, your while statement must use the method I wrote.

Comment: Just edited the code, still asks same question multiple times.. :S

Comment: Completely changed the question xDD Because I can't ask new questions otherway.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you require, you would need to use a RandomAccessFile. Steps:
   First create a RandomAccessFile then:

1. Create a variable called lineStart which is initially set to 0
   (beginning of the file)
2. Read in the file line by line using readline
3. Check whether it is the required line that you wish to insert before
4. If it is the correct place, then lineStart will hold the position
   just before the line you wish to insert before.  Use seek to
   position you at the correct place by initially using seek(0) to
   position you at the start of the file, then seek(lineStart) to get
   the required position. You then use writeChars to write to the file.
   Remember that you have to explicitly write the newline.
5. If it is not where you wish to insert then call  getFilePointer, and
   store value in lineStart

REPEAT STEPS 2-5 UNTIL YOU ARRIVE AT THE DESIRED PLACE FOR INSERTION

Answer (score 1):

You want a **do-while loop**:

```
do {
     //code
} while (expression);
```

Source:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

You probably want something like this:

```
int[] done = new int[100];
int randomquestion;
do{
    randomquestion = (int)(Math.random() * 83 + 1);
    if(done[randomquestion] != 1)
    {
        //ask random question
        //if answer is correct, set done[randomquestion] = 1
        //else just let do-while loop run
    }
    //check if all questions are answered
} while (!areAllQuestionsComplete(done));
```

Here is the method areAllQuestionsComplete(int[]):

```
private boolean areAllQuestionsComplete(int[] list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        if(list[i] != 1)
        {
            return false;//found one false, then all false
        }
    }
    return true;//if it makes it here, then you know its all done
}
```

Looking at your latest code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<done.length; i++)
{
    done[i] = 0;//need default values else wise itll just be NULL!!!
}

do{
    ran = (int)(Math.random() * 83 + 1);
    //before entering the do-while loop, you must set default values in the entire done[] array
    if(done[ran] != 1)
    {
        //ask random question
        //if answer is correct, set done[ran] = 1
        //else just let do-while loop run

        if (ran == 1) { //1
        question = "kala";
        rightanswer = "fish";}
        if (ran == 2) { //2
        question = "peruna";
        rightanswer = "potato";}
        if (ran == 3) { //3
        question = "salaatti";
        rightanswer = "cabbage";}
        if (ran == 4) { //4
        question = "kalkkuna";
        rightanswer = "turkey";}
        if (ran == 5) { //5
        question = "kia";
        rightanswer = "tikku";}

        //YOU MUST HAVE EVERY CONDITION COVERED
        //say your random number makes the number 10
        //you dont set question to  anything at all (hence getting null!)           

        System.out.println(question);
        System.out.print("Vastaus?: ");
        answer = in.readLine();
        //if (answer == rightanswer){
        //must use .equals with Strings...not ==
        if (answer.equals(rightanswer)){            
        right++;
        done[ran] = 1;}
        else{wrong++;}
        }
        //check if all questions are answered
} while (!areAllQuestionsComplete(done));//use the method I wrote!
```

**EDIT:**

You must put default values in the array.  When you create an array, the default value is null.

```
int[] done = new int[100];//create array but everything is null
for(int i = 0; i<done.length; i++)
{
    done[i] = 0;//need default values else wise it'll just be NULL!!!
}
//must be done before the do-while loop starts
```

Finally, make sure your random number generator picks the correct range in numbers.  If you have an array that is size 100, then it's indexes will be 0-99.  This means there is no done[100].  It goes from done[0] to done[99].

If you have done[] be a size of 5, then it will range from done[0] to done[4].  That means you should randomly generate like this:

randomquestion = (int)(Math.random() * 5 );

Comment: May as well have `} while(!allQuestionComplete(done));` and save yourself a few lines of code.

Comment: randomquestion = (int)(Math.random() * 83 + 1);} <--? Is this accidenttaly there?

Comment: I added the whole code to my question. Still got the same problem I had in the beginning + right & wrong answers doesen't count.

Comment: I updated the code like 25 minutes ago.  Did you try it with that?

Comment: Ohh.. :D Nope, I'll try ^^ Thank you!

Comment: O.O Now it seems to give only null questions? Even if the range is `randomquestion = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);`

Comment: Did you make sure put a default value in every index of the done array?  Like loop through it and put in zero.

Comment: I'm not using array list on this program.. :D But true, I should do it with array list! :o Just haven't studied how to use array list.. :S

Comment: You can stick with array.  I meant to .length instead of .size!  Updated answer

Comment: Still the same error.. multiple times same question.. And right & wrong answers doesen't work. >.<

Comment: Post up your latest code on your opening post, so I can see from there

Comment: I updated my answer at the bottom.  You need to set default values in array before entering the do-while loop.  You also need to know that arrays of size n have a range 0 to n-1.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ohh! Now i understood, ty! :D So i first give value for every single done[]! :o Thank you! You are great teacher! ^^

Comment: Yes exactly.  When you create done[], it will just be full of null values.  You need some default values else wise you'll point at null (which causes null pointer exceptions).  Also, remember to keep the range in mind (size n array goes from 0 to n-1)

Comment: And no problem.  |=^)

Comment: It still asks same question multiple times <.< But atleast wrong/right works :D

Comment: Your while statement has the wrong expression and is in the wrong place.  Also, you have a lot of code that doesn't look structured.  You should tab it out so it has common Java structure

Comment: Yes, I will structure it when I get what I want (= make it work):D

Comment: Hmm.. Idk why it keeps giving me question "unidetified" but answers are right!?

Comment: fixed it ^^ But still can't figure out how to make it so that you get one question only once.. :S

Comment: @minisurma That is a different question from the original question...you'll have to make a separate question with the new code...